# Creating a filter in vim in visual mode but only for the selected column range?

Tags: vim, filter

What I'd like to do is select a block of text using `<ctrl>V`  and then run an external filter program that works *only* on that text. You can do this with an internal vim cmd, ie `~` but if I try it with an equivalent C program the whole line for every selected line is processed.  The same thing happens if I use a shell command as my filter.

Is there any way to process just the selected text or pick up the selected column range in the C code?

Sample C code filter:

```
//File: vis.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[],char * envp[])
{
     char c;
     while(!feof(stdin)) fputc(toupper(fgetc(stdin)),stdout) ;

     return 0;
}
```

Vim cmd:

```
<ctrl>V
:'<,'>!vis
```

A sample filter using a shell cmd:

```
:'<,'>! tr '[:lower:]'  '[:upper:]' 
enter code here
```

Testing using vim versions 7.4 and 8.1

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to achieve with `:help :range!` because it is a so-called Ex command and thus only works on *lines*:

- Whole lines are passed to the external command and there is nothing you can do about that, not even using `` `< `` and `` `> `` in your range, which will be rejected anyway.
- The text passed to the external command doesn't have any metadata that could help the external command to figure out what part was selected so what your external command does with the piped-in text is irrelevant.

Since the blocker is on Vim's side, that is where you will have to put your weight.

In Vim, you will have to do something like the following…

1. Yank the visual-block selection to a register of your choosing:

   ```
   "by
   ```
2. Write the content of that register to a temporary file:

   ```
   :let tempfile = tempname()
   :call split(@b, '\n')->writefile(tempfile)
   ```
3. Run that file through your external program and grab the output into a register of your choosing:

   ```
   :call system('vis < ' .. tempname)->setreg('o', 'b')
   ```
4. Delete the temporary file:

   ```
   :call delete(tempfile)
   ```
5. Reselect the previously selected block:

   ```
   gv
   ```
6. Put the new text over the selection:

   ```
   "op
   ```

Note that this is neither tested nor complete: you will have to fill in the blanks yourself. If that wouldn't be the case, where would be the fun?

Resources:

```
:help registers
:help tempname()
:help split()
:help writefile()
:help system()
:help setreg()
:help delete()
:help gv
```

Comment: I'd love to have your level of vimL expertise but it's simpler to yank the block of text into a new empty temporary file, run the external command there, yank the text then go back and paste the modified text over the previous block (gvp).

I was hoping that there was some way to access the range within my C code or limit what was picked up.   Apparently not, unless someone else knows differently.

Comment: Again, there is no metadata whatsoever added to the text being passed to the filter so your filter can't know a) if it comes from a visual-block selection and b) the boundaries of that visual-block selection: all your filter gets as input is some text with a bunch of newlines so there is nothing to do there. The proper solution is not to do it manually and slowly with lots of messy intermediary steps but to write a short function that does the work properly and map it to some key combination or assign it to some custom command.